# template class inheritance problem

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, inheritance, gcc

Can you please tell me, what am I missing?

```
template <class T> struct Base
{
    T data;
    Base(const T &_data):data(_data) { }
};

template <class T> struct Derived : Base<T>
{
    Derived():Base(T()) {} //error: class 'Derived<T>' does not have any field named 'Base'
};
```

Comment: As others have pointed out, it compiles if you change `Base(T())` to `Base<T>(T())`. But can anybody tell us which of the two compilers is correct here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template <class T> struct Derived : Base<T>
{
    Derived():Base<T>(T()) {} 
};
```

Comment: A nice help is a typedef of the base `typedef Base<T> Super`. :) Helps tremendiously when you have more than one template parameter in the base.

Answer (score 1):

There's still the question: Who's right? GCC is right here. Unqualified name lookup does not look into dependent base classes, hence will not find `Base` in the scope of `Base<T>`. You can change your code to the following Standard conformant variant too

```
Derived():Derived::Base(T()) {}
```

If I remember correctly, this is only supported by GCC4.5 though. Earlier versions didn't implement injected class name lookup properly.